# Why aren't my pictures appearing in HTML?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head><title>Real.com</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor= “white” text=“red”>

<h1>welcome to my site!</h1>
<h2>Welcome</h2>

<p> |Home|
<b>Welcome</b></p>

<center><img src=“john_hancock.jpg” width=“400” height=“500”    alt=“john_hancock”></center>
<br>
<a href=“home.html” style=“color:red;”>Home 
<body>
</html>
```

I am trying to upload an image to the website and is trying to create the code for fun, and I am not sure where its going wrong? 
Both the file and Image are both in the same directory as well!
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: you should use " or ' Instead of “

Comment: Try replacing the quotation marks (“ and ”) around your attributes with inch signs (") (or whatever that ASCII character is actually supposed to be).

Comment: A general hint, this will come in handy for you in future: invest some time to find out about and understand your browsers development console. This is a bit browser dependent, but typically you can open it it using the F12 key or by right clicking on some element in the web page and selecting something like "Inspect element". That console offers you a wealth of options to examine things and expermient with it by making temporary changes. The console is a very mighty tool, so it takes a while to understand everything. But once you mastered that step you really advanced to another level!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use bad quotes, use `"` instead of `”`. In whole document. Try to find *replace all* in your text editor.

Image tag will be:

```
<img src="john_hancock.jpg" width="400" height="500" alt="john_hancock">
```

Answer (score 5):

syntax error change any `“ ”` to `""`

Answer (score 3):

You used bad quotation marks. Use `"` instead of `”`.
The proper image tag would be: 
 `<img src="john_hancock.jpg" width="400" height="500" alt="john_hancock">`

Whenever you are not sure where your error is, consider using the w3c HTML-Validator! https://validator.w3.org/
It will tell when your html file contains errors.

Comment: You have a typo around `height` attribute. Open `"`, close `'`.

Answer (score 2):

1) You're are using the so-called typographical quotation marks (“ and ”) while you ought to use the so-called neutral quotation mark (").

2) The img tag needs to be closed, like so:

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

3) You haven't closed your anchor tag.

Comment: `img` in HTML is unpair, `/`is ignored by browsers. Variant without `/` is right (except XML and XHTML with correct mime-type, not text/html). Anchor will be closed be the end of document, works well too.